# Can you find the Inverse Laplace for this Voltage- Angular Displacement function (seen in the picture down Below)?

Tags: inverse-laplace

Can you find the Inverse Laplace for this function (seen in the picture down Below)

Additionally show how to do this on Matlab.

I used Matlab and got the answer below, which I think is wrong, but I think the solution has a dirac delta function because Kt is a constant. Can you provide the correct solution and code?

(Matlab answer)

J L W dirac'''(t) + J R W dirac''(t) + M W k dirac'(t) == V k dirac'(t)

Look at the pictures  posted for the equation in fraction form, as well as my MatLab code where I made; J=Jeq, L=Lm, M=Km,K=Kt,W=W, R=Rm

[Question to do Inverse Laplace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3rGH.jpg)

[Wrong Matlab Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yS7n.png)

Please comment Only Solutions or Correct Answers, Thank you.